# Powershell to export Windows 2008 R2 SMTP Relay Restrictions IPs

Tags: iis, powershell, smtp

I've been searching all over the interwebs and have had no luck so far. Does anyone know if it is possible to use Powershell to export the list of IP address within the SMTP Relay Restrictions section? We have a simple Windows 2008 R2 SMTP server that we use for internal relay and have a grant list of IP addresses that we need to export.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should be worth a try. It grabs the list from the WMI namespace and formats them a bit.

```
#################################################################################################################
#                                                                                                               #
# Name:         Exporting SMTP Relay IP Addresses (only)                                                        #
# Purpose:      Exporting the allowed SMTP Relay IP Addresses for backup purposes as well as troubleshooting    #
# Output:       CSV file                                                                                        #
# Developed by: Stephen Bishop                                                                                  #
# Date:         6/7/2012                                                                                        #
#################################################################################################################
#Note has to be ran on the SMTP Relay#
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -Class "IIsIPSecuritySetting" -Property Name,IPGrant | `
where {$_.Name -eq "SmtpSvc/1"} | `
Select-Object Name,IPGrant | `
foreach  {$_.IPGrant} | Out-File "C:\Documents and Settings\stephen.bishop.oa\Desktop\Exporting SMTP Relay IP Addresses.csv"
```

Credit goes to original author. Found here:

http://community.idera.com/powershell/script_library/m/iis/17033

Comment: Yeah. I had tried that and ran into the same issue as the poster, "Invalid namespace"

Answer (score 0):

Same here.  Searched online an found that it is necessary add "IIS 6.0 WMI compatibility" role.  Select IIS role and hightlight Web Server.  You will be able to select "Add role".